# Link to another page and pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with 2 textboxes and a button (although it could be a link or linkbutton if required).

When the button is clicked I want to link out to another page, but at the same time pass the contents of the 2 textboxes. I'm not too fussed about how this data is transferred as it's non-sensitive, but ideally I'd use something like context items so the handover could be transparent and clean itself up.

I'm pretty sure this is possible in some guise but I can't get my head around the technique to achieve it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use a simple GET \ POST to "transfer" this data.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that data is non-sensitive then you can use the query-string to pass the data like if you want to call Second page then your call should be

```
Second.aspx?val=textbox1.Text&val2=textbox2.Text
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could pass values like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Querystring** to do this below like.

```
Response.Redirect("pagename.aspx?param1="+TextBox1.Text+"&param2="+TextBox2.Text);
```